# Range Frame Axis in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In his book, *The Visual Display of Quantitative Information,* Edward Tufte goes over a proposed improvement on axes called "Range Frames" --
[Range Frame Excerpt (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWK4B.png)

In learning D3, we are taught that axes can be created and then appended to the chart and that a variety of customizations may be applied to them with ranging/css properties, etc. However, the API doesn't seem to convey a way in which these can be used to limit the range of the *line itself,* nor a technique for the manipulation of individual tickmarks. Is there any way of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  Here's a quick implementation that replicates your image with `CSS` only. Here I hard-coded the numbers but for an actual implementation I'd probably apply it in JavaScript to make it dynamic.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="500" height="150"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .two>path{
    stroke-dasharray: 0,30,380;
  }
  
  .three>path{
    stroke-dasharray: 0,5,455;
  }
  
  .three>g:nth-of-type(1)>line{
    stroke: none;
  }
  
  .three>g:nth-last-of-type(1)>line{
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>


<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 50])
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 10 + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
var two = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "two")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 60 + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
var three = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "three")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 110 + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
two.select('path')

</script>
```

---

Here's a dynamic implementation of the 2nd one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="500" height="150"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 20
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 50])
    .range([0, width]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

  var two = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "two")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 60 + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // say you want the line to start at 4 and stop to 46
  two.select('path')
    .attr("d", "M" + x(4) + ",0.6V0.5H" + x(46));
</script>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the great example. It shouldn't be too hard to implement the css attributes you have here in the script, and the max and min could be set with axis.tickValues, no?

Comment: @JustinZiegelmueller, see updates above for a dynamic implementation.